# Test Async-Task using app resources

Tags: java, android, testing, android-asynctask, android-context

I'm testing my android application. I have two android projects, one contains the app, and the other the test classes.

I'm testing a AsyncTask:

```
public class SimilarityTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, SimilarityData> {


    /*More code here*/

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(context.getText(R.string.solving_puzzle));
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(context.getText(R.string.calc_similarity));
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    }



    public SimilarityTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*More code here*/

}
```

As you can see, I create a progress dialog on the activity where this AsyncTask is called using the activity as context. The code works right, but the problem comes when I'm trying to test it.

```
public class SimilarityTaskTest extends ActivityTestCase {

    public void testSimilarity() {
        task = new SimilarityTask(getInstrumentation().getContext());
        task.execute(false);        
    }

}
```

When I use this code, it fails on onPreExecute():

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f07000a
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
at android.content.Context.getText(Context.java:282)
at com.example.tfg.SimilarityTask.onPreExecute(SimilarityTask.java:43)
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
at com.example.tfg.test.SimilarityTaskTest.testSimilarity(SimilarityTaskTest.java:161)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

The exception is quite self explanatory: `R.string.solving_puzzle`, is on my application project not my test project. How can I get a context, as if I was running it from my app project instead my test project?

I've used this code too:

```
public class SimilarityTaskTest extends ActivityTestCase {

    public void testSimilarity() {
        task = new SimilarityTask(getActivity());
        task.execute(false);        
    }

}
```

But `getActivity()` returns `null`. How can I test it?

Answer (score 0):

Using this code works right:

```
public class SimilarityTaskTest extends ActivityTestCase {

    public void testSimilarity() {
        task = new SimilarityTask(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());
        task.execute(false);        
    }
}
```